# Exception: "Timed Out After xx seconds" on wait.until Selenium WebDriver C#

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to figure out how it's possible to wait for a condition in order to login into a web page with Selenium Driver. However it is not as straightforward as it may seem. I'm working around with `Thread.Sleep(3000);` but I'm sure there should be a better solution. So, my code works as follows:

1. Load page with firefox driver.
2. Execute a javascript snnipet to change language (I need to wait for this in order to login).

   ```
   IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)firefox;
   executor.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", idioma_español);
   ```
3. Above instruction leads to a page reload.
4. Next instruction is intented to wait for page to be reloaded

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(newDriver,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
   wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElementValue(element,textToAppear));
   ```
5. Continue to login.

However, when I run the code, it throws the following exception:

[image]

Looking closer into de output, I found this:

[image]

[image]

I tried with different expected conditions such as: `TextToBePresentInElement`,`ElementExists`; but it throws the same exception.

I also tried with `ExecuteAsyncScript("arguments[0].click();", idioma_español);` method, but it throws "Document was unloaded " exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the text element has been replaced, so the element was stale. I think you can solve it by fetch the new element every time. See code below:

```
public bool WaitForTextToAppear(IWebDriver driver, By elementLocator, string textToAppear, int timeoutInSec=10)
{
    IWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
    wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSec);
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300);
    try
    {
        wait.Until(d => IsTextPresentedIn(d, elementLocator, textToAppear));
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}

private bool IsTextPresentedIn(IWebDriver driver, By elementLocator, string textToAppear)
{
    try
    {
        var elements = driver.FindElements(elementLocator);
        if (elements.Count>0 && elements[0].Text.Equals(textToAppear, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
// using the web driver extension.
bool textAppeared = WaitForTextToAppear(driver, By.CssSelector("selector-of-the-text-element"), "HERE IS THE EXPECTED TEXT");
```

Comment: Hello Buaban. I tried to implement your code but I got the following errors. Do I need to wrap your code to WebDriver interfaces?
1. WaitForTextToAppear method it is not contained in IWebDriver definition.
2. IsTextPresentedIn method it is not contained in IWebDriver definition.
3. First() method it is not contained in IWebElement.

Comment: Can you add the new implementation in your question? Can you check parameters of the new methods? The first parameter must be `this IWebDriver driver`

Comment: Hello Buaban. 
A picture is worth a thousand words: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-kELnXouARQZTRZVjNtUGw3V1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DaniAya It looks like some extensions are not added to your project. By the way, I’ve updated the answer to pass the driver by reference. Please try.

Comment: Thank you for take the time to help me in this issue. Now I have just 2 errors in WaitForTextToAppear and WaitForTextToAppear call. Again, you can see those issues in the next picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-kELnXouARQVmhXTTEzdXRTNWs/view

Comment: @DaniAya I’ve missed one line. The answer has been updated at `wait.Until(d=>IsTextPresentedIn...`

Comment: Hello Buaban. Amazing work. I would have to spend days finding a solution. Thank you very much.